# jQWidgets and Document Standards

Tags: internet-explorer, jqwidget

I am using jQWidgets to develop the UI. The grids load fine as long as the document mode in IE is IE 8 standards. However, as soon I we change the document mode to anything else, such as IE 7 or Quirks mode, the grid/all screens become very slow. The version of jQwidgets we are using is version 3.2.2
Can someone please let me know why is this the case and how it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

IE7 is slow browser so do not expect pretty fast results in it compared to new web browsers. It also much depends on which features you use and how you use them. Some require more resources than others.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 or old browsers may not support many of the JQuery functions and JQWidgets is purely based on javascript / Jquery, using 'JQWidgets ' in these may result to erroneous behavior.